# how to connect to the virtual machine via remote desktop on the screen without enabling remote desktop check option in virtualbox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, remote-desktop

as stated in my question. I'm trying to have connection to a virtual machine remotely without enabling virtualbox remote desktop  screen. using the network host only. but I could not make this connection without having to enable the option on the screen.
according to my research it is possible because  applications as  Andy or genymotion  does this.
if anyone knows the subject. appreciate your help